# XCode Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Tags: ios

I am having an issue where when I swipe up on my app to close in the simulator, the app will not open again unless re-run. I am getting an error `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`. I looked this up and read the issue may be related to CPU usage on the device but mine is very low. I am not even sure how to begin debugging as it is not clear where the issue is coming from. I am getting the user's location but I am doubtful that is causing the issue. I've also read a bit about background tasks causing this but am not confident this is my issue. I know this is a vague issue and I am happy to post code snippets once I can narrow down where the problem may lie. Does anyone know where I can begin debugging?

Comment: I get the same error in the debugger console whenever I quit my app in the simulator and since I can restart my app in the simulator, signal 9 might not be relevant to your issue but something to expect in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

You get the "Terminated due to signal 9" message, when your app gets killed. It might occcur when you swipe up and kill your app when it is running or else if you go to settings and change privacy settings for your app like changing location services or camera permissions for the app. It might also happen when you are debugging in your iphone device and the lightning cable is faulty, it will disconnect and the terminated signal will be thrown in the debugger.

Comment: exactly, it was happening with me when I was changing the Permission settings for 'Motion & Fitness' manually; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to debug here. What you're describing is the expected behaviour of the task manager: swiping up kills a running app, in a way that cannot be intercepted or denied, using signal 9, `SIGKILL`.

Comment: so there is no way to open an app again once it is swiped up without re-running?

Comment: No, except for some special cases involving location access in the background. Generally, the system honors the user's very explicit request of not running an app anymore when killing it via the task manager, and does not automatically restart that app.